# Joint PDFs of Exponentials - error in textbook?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I found this example in my textbook (see screenshot below, I apologize for the poor lighting) and I am confused how they found the joint PDF f(x,y). X and Y are given as i.i.d exponential random variables with common parameter.

I thought that the joint PDF of two independent random variables was the product of their PDFs.

If the PDFs of the exponential RV's are:

$$f_{X}(x) = λe^{-λx} $$
$$f_{Y}(y) = λe^{-λy} $$

I think the PDF should be:

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = λ^2e^{-λ(x+y)}$$

My textbook image is below. Is there some algebra that I am missing? Or is this a mistake in the textbook?

[image]

Comment: @geetha290krm The difference between equation 6-133 in the image and CMBel's pdf is the interpretation of the $\lambda$ parameter.  CMBel reads it as rate of the distribution, the text is using it as the scale (or mean).  It is a common and annoying lack of standardisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two versions of exponential distribution, which depend on whether the $\lambda$ parameter represents the *rate* or the *scale*.

Your text source is using the *scale* parameter.  You've learned the version using the *rate* parameter.

The *scale* of the distribution is the mean.   The *rate* is the inverse of the mean.

$$Z\sim\mathcal{Exp}(\lambda)\text{ where }\lambda\text{ is the scale means that }f_Z(z)=\lambda^{-1}\mathrm e^{-z/\lambda}\text{ and so }\mathsf E(Z)=\lambda\\ Z\sim\mathcal{Exp}(\lambda)\text{ where }\lambda\text{ is the rate means that }f_Z(z)=\lambda\mathrm e^{-\lambda z}\text{ and so }\mathsf E(Z)=\lambda^{-1}$$

---

This is but one of many instances of a lack of a single standard in families of distributions. Always check to see exactly which a new text uses.

That they just called it "the parameter" and did not clarify is bad performance on their behalf.  Perhaps they did so earlier, but it is a well known source of confusion.